# capturing image from camera and overlaying another bitmap before we save it

Tags: android, android-camera

here tempdata is the data captured from camera, savephoto(Bitmap)    is a method am using to save the image taken from camera, and it is executing accurately ,, 
BUt on [2]
i am overlaying  another bitmap ,, and when i am calling the savephoto(p)
it is creating an empty file in the memorycard ...
not saving any image.
how can i overlay the two bitmap on top of each other

```
[1]File Imgname = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(tempdata,0,tempdata.length);
imv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
savePhoto(bmp);

[2]Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0,0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 50, 50, null);
savePhoto(b);
```

any help will be greatly appreciated 
thanx

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this after getting after getting bitmap from camera (assume bitmap1) and your bitmap to overlay on top of bitmap1 (assume bitmap2) 
call this overlayMark() with your bitmaps it will return overlay bitmap that is your required bitmap . you can save that bitmap..

```
private Bitmap overlayMark(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)    { 
   int bh = originalBitmap.getHeight();
   int bw = originalBitmap.getWidth();
   Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bw,bh,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
   Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay); 
   canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
   canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0,0, null);
   return bmOverlay;
}
```

Comment: i tried this code ,, but it is not working when i save the bmOverlay in the memory card , it creates a file of 0.0kb , means an empty file ,,,,

Comment: i am passinf the bmOverlay into a method, which in turn saves the file but it is making an empty file , the code to save is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939719/how-to-retrieve-an-image-from-memory-card-in-this-scenario

Comment: This is the best example for saving bitmap http://stackoverflow.com/a/7887114/964741