# How to retrieve an image from memory card in this scenario

Tags: android-canvas, android-sdcard, android-file

i am saving an image by passing a bitmap to the savephoto(Bitmap function)
now i want to retrieve the photo which is saved ,, how to do that  i am new in android , plz give me the code of retrival and also convert it into Bitmap

```
public void savePhoto(Bitmap b2)
{
File imageFileFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Rotate");
mageFileFolder.mkdir();
FileOutputStream out = null;
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
String date = fromInt(c.get(Calendar.MONTH))
+ fromInt(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
+ fromInt(c.get(Calendar.YEAR))
+ fromInt(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY))
+ fromInt(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE))
+ fromInt(c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
File  imageFileName = new File(imageFileFolder, date.toString() + ".jpg");
try
{
out = new FileOutputStream(imageFileName);
b2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
out.flush();
out.close();
out = null;
} catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

thanx helping :)