# Is it possible to record Augmented reality videos?

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I have seen many many AR APPs which allow user to see video's/ 3D animations over markers? But I have not seen an app allowing to record the video or click a picture.

I have seen a few posts on stackoverflow which mention about copying an image over camera image to get overlay AR image effect

[Image overlay with camera captured image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352062/image-overlay-with-camera-captured-image-in-android)

Does that mean it is impossible to record videos playing an AR element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general,in AR app you can add object in the image or place image over camera view. If you want to create video you have to connect this image to every image of video sequence. By making little differences you can create animated object.

There is no problem to capture augumented picture or video.. developers just have not needed it yet. But nice idea  ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem. practical way to overlay virtual 2d/3d object on camera view in AR is to use openGL to draw virtual object (can be either a 3D object or 2D texture) on a texture layer of camera view. Through the rasterization process in OpenGL pipeline, each pixel in the display surface is filled with the proper color, so that a frame mix with real and virtual is presented. The pixels stored in a framebuffer, that could be saved easily.

Comment: Could you give me an github example?